# Grails - strange JRE Error - Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:149)

Tags: windows, grails, runtime-error, java

I'm pretty much new to Grails, however I learn as I go with a mid-size app development.

By now I was really ethusiastic abut Grails and how easy and fast in development it was - by now :)

I have a domain class with over 40 proprties. I run it locally on development env (standard glassfish + H2 on Windows 7) and on my server with Tomcat + PostgreSQL on Debian and everything went smoothly and identical on both environment (with a little difference in flush after save() in H2 and PostgreSQL). I added one more property and on my development environment I get some strange JRE error (as I googled it it's related to native methods exception handling). The application is starting fine, I can add new objects to this class from the code level, I can display them with toString method in other related classes, however as soon as I go to the standard Show view for a particular instance, I get the error. The log is below:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:149), pid=10776, tid=4684
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: 7.0_07-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp 
#
```

I get this error no matter what kind of new property I add (even the simplest int), no matter whether I use scaffold or not...It seems that adding one more porperty is causing something to exceed some treshold and throw an exception from a native C++ code which is inproperly handled by JRE and I can't get to know what the problem is. Sometimes I don't get the error, but the CPU goes nuts and the browser is waiting for the server to respond with the show view forever.

What is even stranger, when I put the prod war on Tomcat everything runs smoothly as expected....

Anyone ever expperienced similar problem or has any suggestions what and where to check to resolve the problem? It's pretty uncomfortable to test the app during development on production env...

Comment: sounds like a bug - what version of Grails?

Comment: Grails 2.1.0, Java 1.7.0_07, IDE - GGTS 3.0

Comment: That's funny - after grails clean (should have done it earlier) I was able to once access the Create view - second click ended again with the fatal error...

Comment: 1. Check the Java version on your Debian if different. 
2. Upgrade java the Windows development machine to the latest (1.7.0_15) 
3. Make sure the JRE has enough memory while at it (-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m)
4. If no luck, proceed with installing MySQL on the windows server and see if it runs better.

Good luck!